# Vue component styles are not loaded in Puppeteer

Tags: vue.js, puppeteer

I am trying to create a PDF of Vue component which uses Bootstrap Vue for style. I've successfully created PDF using Puppeteer but the styles are missing. I have added style tags also and still it's not working.

```
await page.addStyleTag({ url: 'https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' })

await page.addStyleTag({ url: 'https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css' })
```

Can some one help?

Comment: I think that your style tag should look like `@import('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')`

Comment: @IVOGELOV can you explain a bit more? I am trying to add style in Puppeteer and not in Vue

Comment: Your style tag is not valid CSS - it is missing the CSS selector. But even with a CSS selector - there is no CSS rule with name `url`. It looks like you want to inject a whole CSS file - and in this case you need the `@import` CSS statement. For more information - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import